# Pentax PocketJet 3 Plus - Add printer

Tags: printing

I have a Pentax PocketJet 3 Plus that I want to use with my linux machine but I can't find a linux driver, only windows one. Is there anything that I can do to make it work or should I just forget this idea?

This is what I get from dmesg:

```
[ 5562.920208] usb 2-3.4: new full-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 5563.014188] usb 2-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a17, idProduct=3406
[ 5563.014195] usb 2-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5563.014198] usb 2-3.4: Product: PocketJet3PlusB
[ 5563.014201] usb 2-3.4: Manufacturer: PENTAX
[ 5563.014204] usb 2-3.4: SerialNumber: 54027
[ 5563.015492] usblp 2-3.4:1.0: usblp1: USB Unidirectional printer dev 17 if 0 alt 0 proto 1 vid 0x0A17 pid 0x3406
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find drivers for the printer
[here](http://jfbdtp.com/Pentax/drivers.html).
A detailed instruction on how to install it is included.